# Is it possible to reference a C# class that's not defined in a .nswag file?

Tags: c#, swagger, nswag

I have a .Net Core project with multiple APIs that are generated by using Swagger (Nswag). 
I also have a few projects that contain shared classes that are used in multiple of the APIs and are not generated.

Now I want one generated controller method to return an object of a type that's specified in one of these model projects and written by myself (not generated by Swagger)

Is this even possible and, if yes, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 1):

You can exclude some dtos from being generated (i think its the ExcludedTypes setting) and add a using to your namespace (AdditionalNamespaceUsages)